# docker-compose build --parallel - run command before build specific image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, parallel-processing

my `docker-compose.yml` file is below.

I want to build parallel those images - I am running the a command `docker-compose build --parallel`

BUT I want to run a command before it builds the images of `service2` & `service3` while building `service1` - parallel.

When the command will be finished it will join to the building-parallel-process.

```
version: '3.4'
  services:
    service1:
      image: "company/service1:${TAG}"
      build:
        context: ./folder/service1/
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    service2:
      image: "company/service2:${TAG}"
      build:
        context: ./folder/service2/
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    service3:
      image: "company/service3:${TAG}"
      build:
        context: ./folder/service3
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Compose doesn't really have any sort of workflow handling like this, especially around building images.  It's assumed that building an image only depends on the local source tree and nothing else.  Compose also doesn't have any ability to run non-Docker commands or launch temporary containers as part of the `up` workflow.

The good news is that re-running a build is very quick if nothing has changed.  So with the workflow you've described, you might separately build the first image, run the command, and then rebuild everything; re-rebuilding the first image will take almost no time and you won't get a new image.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Build the one image that needs special handling
docker-compose build service1

# Run the command
the_command

# Rebuild everything in parallel (service1 will be a no-op)
docker-compose build --parallel
```

If you can run the preparatory step in a Dockerfile `RUN` command that might be easier to manage.  If that needs software that isn't ordinarily part of your image, you could use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to do it in effectively a temporary image.